# what is difference between '../js/vue' and 'test/data/js/vue.js'?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm not sure about this error.
I use require.js to require file in js folder , like this:

```
require(['../js/vue'],function(){});
```

But i add baseUrl , it have error

```
require([baseUrl+'/js/vue'],function(){});
```

it is similar to

```
require(['test/data/js/vue'],function(){});
//Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
//Uncaught Error: Script error for
```

If i add extension .js:

```
require(['test/data/js/vue.js'], function(){}); //It work fine
```

what is difference between '../js/vue' and 'test/data/js/vue.js'?

Answer (score 1):

the `..` stands for one directory up. Let's say you created a src folder and within the source folder you have 3 folders, html, css, js. For example when you want to go from your html directory to your js dir. You can do that by typing `../js/FILE.js` but you could also do `/src/js/FILE.js`. **But** there is something called path traversal exploits which can be caused by going up directories with `../`, so for that reason, I recommend you to just never use `../` . And aside from having security issues, in my opinion it is way easier to read the full directory with parent directories then just the `../`.

So in short the difference is that with the `..` you first go up one directory and then down to where you want to go. Without the `..` you only go down in the file system. That makes it safer to use than using the `..`.